# 英語が残っている: 基本設定 > Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

[image: Enable keyboard shortcuts (when enabled, press ? for help)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Keyboard shortcuts

キーボードショートカット

> Enable keyboard shortcuts (チェックボックスのtitle属性)

キーボードショートカットを有効にする

> Enable keyboard shortcuts (when enabled, press ? for help)

キーボードショートカットを有効にする（有効にした状態で ? を押すとヘルプが表示されます）